# How to add Calender in view in Swift and customize it

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

How can i add Calender as i am a newbie in swift. I also want to customize it so i want something with customization option.![enter image description here][1]

How to use calender with showing number on each date.

Comment: Please share some code. What have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

The iOS library doesn't come with a UICalendar that you can use and customize. You probably don't want a calendar... interacting with a 30+ buttons on a small screen with large fingers isn't fun. If you insist you can try this library I found with a quick google search

https://github.com/Mozharovsky/CVCalendar

No idea how it's going to turn out for you... I would recommend using a UICollectionView, UITableView, UIDatePicker or a cominbation of them to display the information you want. It's much easier to rethink the workflow to something that makes sense for the device your programming for rather than forcing something you think may be a good idea.